# Why is glFramebufferTexture a NULL pointer when GLEW_ARB_framebuffer_object is non-zero?

Tags: linux, opengl, glew

My code looks roughly like this:

```
GLenum glewStatus = glewInit();
if (glewStatus != GLEW_OK)
    exit(1);

if (!GLEW_ARB_framebuffer_object)
    exit(1);

printf("%p\n", glFramebufferTexture);
```

This prints 0, so that explains why calling `glFramebufferTexture()` immediately segfaults.

However, why is it 0? A lot of the other framebuffer functions are working just fine (e.g. `glBindFramebuffer`, `glFramebufferRenderbuffer`, and `glBindFramebuffer`).

Do I need to initialise GLEW or the extension differently?

Comment: Did you call `glewInit()` after you created a GL context?

Comment: And: did you set `glewExperimental` to true?

Comment: Yep, I created the GL context first. Setting `glewExperimental` to `GL_TRUE` seemed to fix the problem, thanks! Feel free to create an answer so I can accept it. It would be nice to have an explanation of why the extension test succeeded, though. Did I check for the wrong extension?

Comment: @Vegard: as Reto Koradi pointet out in his answer, you probably checked the wrong _function_. However, my point with `glewExperimental` was the opposite. Setting it to true can leads to the situation that it can load the extension pointers in a core profile, but will report all the extensions as missing (and getting a non-NULL function pointer does _not_ guarantee that the extension is available).

Comment: @Vegard: What kind of context are you using? 3.2+ Core? GLEW is a bit out of date when it comes to querying the extensions string. It still tries to do `glGetString (GL_EXTENSIONS)` instead of looping over each one individually using `glGetStringi (N, GL_EXTENSIONS)`. The later behavior is ***required*** in a 3.2+ Core context or 3.1 without `GL_ARB_compatibility`. GLEW has a stupider alternative that it tries if you set `glewExperimental` to `GL_TRUE`, and that is to simply try and load the function pointers for ***every*** function in an extension to determine if the extension is supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glFramebufferTexture()` is a newer entry point than `glBindFramebuffer()` and other FBO related entry points. In the core OpenGL spec, `glFramebufferTexture()` was added in 3.2, while the rest of the FBO functionality was part of 3.0. `glFramebufferTexture()` was also not part of ARB_framebuffer_object.

You can use `glFramebufferTexture2D()` in most cases, which is part of the original FBO functionality. `glFramebufferTexture()` is only different for things like texture arrays, cube maps, etc.